Calculation on All Values of a Column that Respects Filters on Other Columns
Let us assume that we have a table of data that looks like this:

Let us also assume that we have added the table to the Data Model within Excel (Version 2404 Build 16.0.17531.20152), 64-bit, and that we have created a basic pivot table as follows (with some value filtering applied):

If I create a measure to show the standard deviation of all the StandardDeviation values using the following formula (this is not my exact use case; I intend to use such a value along with other values, but for the sake of keeping the example simple, I have opted to simply show it as is):
=STDEVX.P(ALL(Table2[StandardDeviation]), Table2[StandardDeviation]))
Then my pivot table looks like this:

The problem arises when I want to alter the value filter(s) on other columns within the pivot table: the StdDev of StdDev value stays the same.
Through watching this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gD8yLTtyW1k, I learned about ALLSELECTED. Modifying my DAX formula to
=CALCULATE(STDEV.P(Table2[StandardDeviation]), ALLSELECTED(Table2[RefOne]), ALLSELECTED(Table2[RefTwo]))
I saw no difference in the StdDev of StdDev value as I changed the value filters on RefOne and RefTwo until I started altering the RefOne and RefTwo column filters via Slicers instead of using the column value filtering functionality:

My question is this: Is there a way to perform a calculation that takes as input all of the current values of a column that also respects the filters in other columns of the same pivot table without having to resort to slicers?
.

Maybe some textual data to help us help you ? :)
